# Throw an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException exception when start?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to use es5,But throw an exception after start it.

```
[2016-11-08T10:21:15,731][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] unable to install syscall filter: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: seccomp unavailable: CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
```

es:5.0.0

java:1.8.0_111

system:Linux version 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64,CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Comment: according to this comment " its just that if you became vulnerable to a security bug in java itself, you would be left defenseless". https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15271

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829908/elasticsearch-5-0-0-aplha4-wont-start-without-setting-vm-max-map-count